# Обратная польская запись для Pascal-выражений

Tags: c++, польская-запись

```
void semantic::create_reverse_polish() {
    reverse_polish_out.clear();
    while (!reverse_polish_stack.empty())
        reverse_polish_stack.pop();

    while (!reverse_polish_in.empty()) {
        const csymbol sym = reverse_polish_in.front();
        reverse_polish_in.erase(reverse_polish_in.begin());
        // Если символ является константой или переменной, добавляем его к выходной строке
        if (sym.type == st_const || ident_table[sym.ident].value.type == ct_integer || ident_table[sym.ident].value.type == ct_real || ident_table[sym.ident].value.type == ct_char || ident_table[sym.ident].value.type == ct_boolean) {
            reverse_polish_out.push_back(sym);
            may_be_unary = false;
        }
            // Если символ является открывающей скобкой, помещаем его в стек
        else if (sym.op == op_l_bracket) {
            reverse_polish_stack.push(sym);
            may_be_unary = true;
        }
            // Если символ является закрывающей скобкой
        else if (sym.op == op_r_bracket) {
            may_be_unary = false;
            // До тех пор, пока верхним элементом стека не станет открывающая скобка, выталкиваем элементы из стека в выходную строку. При этом открывающая скобка удаляется из стека, но в выходную строку не добавляется
            while (!reverse_polish_stack.empty() && reverse_polish_stack.top().op != op_l_bracket) {
                reverse_polish_out.push_back(reverse_polish_stack.top());
                reverse_polish_stack.pop();
            }
            if (!reverse_polish_stack.empty())
                reverse_polish_stack.pop();
        }
            // Если символ является оператором о1, тогда:
        else if (reverse_polish_is_kw_or_op(sym)) {
            if (sym.op != op_sub && sym.op != op_add && sym.kw != kw_not)
                may_be_unary = sym.op == op_equal || sym.op == op_not_equal || sym.op == op_less || sym.op == op_greater || sym.op == op_less_or_equal || sym.op == op_greater_or_equal;

            // пока (если оператор o1 право-ассоциированный) приоритет o1 меньше приоритета оператора, находящегося на вершине стека
            if (may_be_unary && (sym.op == op_add || sym.op == op_sub || sym.kw == kw_not))
                while (!reverse_polish_stack.empty() && reverse_polish_stack.top().op != op_l_bracket && operators_priorities[sym.type == st_op ? sym.op : sym.kw] > operators_priorities[reverse_polish_stack.top().type == st_op ? reverse_polish_stack.top().op : reverse_polish_stack.top().kw]) {
                    if (reverse_polish_stack.top().op != op_l_bracket)
                        reverse_polish_out.push_back(reverse_polish_stack.top());
                    reverse_polish_stack.pop();
                }
            else
                // пока (если оператор o1 ассоциированный, либо лево-ассоциированный) приоритет o1 меньше либо равен приоритету оператора, находящегося на вершине 
                while (!reverse_polish_stack.empty() && reverse_polish_stack.top().op != op_l_bracket && operators_priorities[sym.type == st_op ? sym.op : sym.kw] >= operators_priorities[reverse_polish_stack.top().type == st_op ? reverse_polish_stack.top().op : reverse_polish_stack.top().kw]) {
                    if (reverse_polish_stack.top().op != op_l_bracket)
                        reverse_polish_out.push_back(reverse_polish_stack.top());
                    reverse_polish_stack.pop();
                }

            if (may_be_unary && sym.op == op_sub)
                reverse_polish_stack.push(csymbol(st_op, op_unary_minus));
            else if (may_be_unary && sym.op == op_add)
                reverse_polish_stack.push(csymbol(st_op, op_unary_plus));
            else
                reverse_polish_stack.push(sym);
        }
    }
    while (!reverse_polish_stack.empty()) {
        reverse_polish_out.push_back(reverse_polish_stack.top());
        reverse_polish_stack.pop();
    }
}
```

На вход функции подается инфиксная запись выражения. Дело в том, что выражения, в которых содержится `not`, обрабатываются неправильно. Например, для выражения `not a + b <= -4` на выходе должно быть `a b + 4 - <= not`, а получается `a not b + 4 - <=`, то есть как будто not применяется для `a`, а не для всего выражения.

Приоритет операций (другие операции содержаться в выражении не могут):

```
unordered_map<int, int> semantic::operators_priorities = {
    {kw_not, 1}, {op_unary_plus, 1}, {op_unary_minus, 1},
    {op_mul, 2}, {op_div, 2}, {kw_div, 2}, {kw_mod, 2}, {kw_and, 2},
    {op_add, 3}, {op_sub, 3}, {kw_or, 3},
    {op_equal, 4}, {op_less, 4}, {op_greater, 4}, {op_not_equal, 4}, {op_less_or_equal, 4}, {op_greater_or_equal, 4}
};
```

Comment: не особо знаю pascal, но если верить букварям, то в выражении `not a + b <= -4` `not` и должен применятся к `a`... что не так то? если нужно, чтобы применялся ко всему выражению, то  сделай приоритет `not` ниже (больше по числу), чем у сравнения...